# Unable to close error message window

Tags: 13.10

have a weird issue, when ever i plug in iphone into my ubuntu 13.10.

I get this error

[image]

Not much of an issue, the annoying thing is I cannot close this dialogue. Clicking Ok does nothing and Clicking X does nothing.

Comment: Try running `xkill` in the terminal, then left-click on the error window. This should get rid of it (the window).

Answer (score 2):

Try `Esc` button. It will close the popup.